# get remainder function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a script in shorter way but it doesn't work..

It is not really clear as i see.. so: here all of the codes..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('button').click(function(){
 var benen = $('[name=benen]').val();


 var zadelmaat = benen * 1.89;
var kadermaat = benen * 0.69; 

var remainder = zadelmaat % 2;
if(remainder % 2 == 0)
{
return zadelmaat;
}else
{
zadelmaat = zadelmaat - remainder;
}

var remainder = kadermaat % 2;
if(remainder % 2 == 0)
{
return kadermaat;
}else
{
kadermaat = kadermaat - remainder;
} 

$('.zadelmaat').append(zadelmaat);
$('.kadermaat').append(kadermaat);
return false;

});
});
```

That works for me! But what i am trying to change is to write a simple function to get rid of the remainder(in case)!

I hope it s more clear now...

Thnx!

Comment: Are you seriously trying to compute the remainder of the remainder?

Comment: What problem is it that you're trying to solve?

Comment: From what does the first code `return`, is that an event handler? The second one always computes `length` and `height` and always returns `false`.

Comment: `getRemainder()` doesn't have a `return` statement in the `else` clause.

Comment: The top code has `return` statements, but it's not in a function, which makes no sense.

Comment: …and `x = x - remainder;` doesn't work as `x` is not a pointer to `length`/`height` but a separate variable

Comment: PLEASE indent your code readably.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript, that's what's wrong... Try running it through http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: By the looks of it, you're trying to make the number be an even number? `2*Math.floor(x/2)`, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
function getRemainder(x) { 
    var remainder = x % 2;
    return x - remainder;
}
```

You forgot to `return` the result in case the remainder was not 0. And you don't need to explicitly test for that, as `x - 0 == x`.

Comment: I still get the remainder what i mean is getRemainder(length); gives 28,34000000

Comment: And what do you want to get instead? What is your input for that?

Comment: I changed my question, look up please..thnx

Comment: @user2045937: So you intend not to append anything when either zadelmaat or kadermaat is even, but append the floored values else?

Comment: I don't compare zadelmaat en kadermaat in these codes. all i am trying to do if the result of benen * 1.89 has remainder then substract that remainder..that's it! i just wanna write a function for remainder..

Comment: @user2045937: And that's what my function does! [Here you can try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/AEqqF/)

Comment: I got it! thnx for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You pass a value to the function, not a pointer. To make it work you must add `return x;` to the else clause.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to this:
you only return a different value if it is not ==0

```
function getRemainder(x) { 
    var remainder = x % 2;
    if(x % 2 != 0) {
        x = x - remainder;
    }
    return x
 }
```

Comment: that gives result but still with the remainder. so You don't subtract the remainder... but what i am trying to the sth like that!

Answer (score 1):

Someone edited your code which seems to be an invalid edit as it really changed the question/problem.

Simplified code for function:

```
function getRemainder (x) {
   return x % 2 === 0 ? x : x = x - x % 2;
};
```

I made some assumptions from the original code in a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eqQzM/

alerts "28:6"

Comment: Complicated? uses an unary conditioninal re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators and creates no temporary variables.

Comment: By "unary conditional" you mean "ternary operator"? But yes, it's complicated (and inefficient), just `return x - x % 2;` would do it as well :-)